# Laravel - On Install New Library - Remove / Downgrade Vendor Packages

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I have an issue.

I download my live application. There are so many packages are installed into the Vendor Directory. I need to install one more directory there through composer.

My Issues is that when I write command. Like

```
composer require jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper
```

Whats happening, composer removing some packages and downgrading other packages then install the above Library.

[image]

I want that, Composer install that directory without removing and downgrading the vendors other packages.

Or there is any way that, all the vendor packages sync with composer. ? so when I run `composer update` then it will update all the packages. ?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the complete output that you get when running this command?

Comment: @xabbuh , I have given the output in image. Can you please review.

Comment: Compare your PHP version on server and your local machine. I assume they differ.

Comment: there is any way that, all the vendor packages sync with composer. ? so I update then it will update all the packages. ?

Comment: I was developed complete application on that same xampp server as I an running that command.